# jQuery scrollTop animation returns Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am having a problem whit my jQuery code (is below) and I don't understand why?

I am trying to give my site a `scrollTop` animation, that works fine normally, but when I want to use a `ul li ul li a` constellation even though jQuery, fires it gets stuck, and I get an error like this:

*`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`*

I have a fiddle with my code and the exact same situation again: When I click on the for example `href="#5.1"`

updated code:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(event) {
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : $(location).offset().top -10
    }, 800, function () {
       var location 2 = location.replace( "\\" ,"");
    window.location.hash = location2;
});
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GKyg4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is straight forward! You must escape `.`, just like this:

```
<a href="#5\.1">Punkt 10: Header und Footer ohne ID ansprechen</a>
```

[Online Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur42a/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped.

[Selectors | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

#### EDIT 1:

In case you're trying to avoid having that `\` in the actual URL, just try removing it, by applying simple *regex* to you location variable:

```
var location = location.replace(/\\/g,"");
```

Comment: hi it worked perfect ^^
but now I have s \ after the hash how can i let javascript replace \ after use?
this doesn't work
'location.replace( "\" ,"");'

Comment: No sure what you meant? Can you post an example to jsFiddle please?

Comment: http://goo.gl/8Yyhjf  here its were my site is hosted (for now) 
if you click on point 5 a) you will see in your after the URL this:
#5\.1 and I would like it to be #5.1 
I have edited my code (up)